# CSRF token mismatch in Apache Flask due to session reset

Tags: apache, python-2.7, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I have an example of a CSRF protected form that runs perfectly in the development environment (Flask runs the server itself with `app.run`) but fails when I run the app via `mod_wsgi` in Apache. The versions I use are:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix)
Python 2.7.3
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-WTF==0.9.5
WTForms==2.0
Flask-KVSession==0.4
simplekv==0.8.4
```

The reason that it fails is a `csrf_token` mismatch during form validation. I log the contents of the `flask.session` and `flask.request.form` at the beginning of the view and the contents of the session again at the end of the view. In development mode the content of the `csrf_token` in the session stays constant across multiple requests, for example,

```
<KVSession {'csrf_token': '79918c1e3191e4d4fe89a9499f576404a18be8e4'}>
```

The contents of the form are transmitted correctly in both cases, e.g.,

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', u'1403778775.86##34f1447f1b8c78808f4e71f2ff037bcd1df41dcd'),
('time', u'8'), ('submit', u'Go'), ('dose', u'Low')])
```

When I run my app via Apache the session contents are reset with each request. At the beginning of the view the session contents are empty:

```
<KVSession {}>
```

and then a new token is set each time which leads to the mismatch. Currently, my `__init__.py` module looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from simplekv.memory import DictStore
from flaskext.kvsession import KVSessionExtension


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("myapp.config.Config")

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

store = DictStore()
KVSessionExtension(store, app)

from . import views
```

I removed the `KVSession` statements and that didn't change the problem. So I think server side sessions are not the culprit.

And yes, I have set the `SECRET_KEY` to `os.urandom(128)` in the config.

The relevant (I think) section of my `httpd.conf` is:

```
Listen url.com:8090
<VirtualHost url.com:8090>

    # --- Configure VirtualHost ---

    LogLevel debug

    ServerName url.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/flaskapp/htdocs

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/flaskapp/htdocs/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # --- Configure WSGI Listening App(s) ---

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite user=me group=us processes=2 threads=10
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/flaskapp/wsgi/wsgi.py

    <Directory /path/to/flaskapp/wsgi/>
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # --- Configure Static Files ---

    Alias /static/ /path/to/flaskapp/htdocs/static/
    Alias /tmp/ /path/to/flaskapp/htdocs/tmp/

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know about Apache settings or mod_wsgi with Flask interactions that could cause the session not to persist between requests?

Comment: What does your mod_wsgi configuration look like?

Comment: @SeanVieira I added part of the `httpd.conf`. I only load the `mod_wsgi` module (`LoadModule wsgi_module lib/httpd/mod_wsgi.so`) but did not change its configuration.

Comment: My *guess* is that you are getting handled by two different processes each time and because you use `os.urandom` to create your secret key when your code is loaded this results in each process having a *different* secret, which isn't what you want.  To confirm, try a hard-coded secret key and see if that fixes the issue.  If it does, you can generate a secret key at deploy time and store it either on disk or in memory and reference that for your production secret key. [See here for more](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading#Sharing_Of_Global_Data)

Comment: @SeanVieira you are on to *something* at least. A fixed key did not solve my troubles, the session was still empty at the beginning of a request. Reducing the number of processes in the config to `1` did solve it. I will peruse the documentation further, thank you for that link.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that you store your sessions using `Flask-KVSession`, and provide a memory based `DictStore` as a storage:

```
from simplekv.memory import DictStore

store = DictStore()
KVSessionExtension(store, app)
```

**Root cause**

In a single-threaded environment, this will work. However, when multiple processes comes into play, they do not share the same memory, and multiple instances of `DictStore` are created, one per process. As a result, when two subsequent requests are served by two different processes, first request will not be able to pass session changes to a next request.

Or, even shorter: *Two processes = two CSRF tokens. Not good.*

**Solution**

Use a persistent storage. This is what I use:

```
def configure_session(app):
    with app.app_context():
        if config['other']['local_debug']:
            store = simplekv.memory.DictStore()
        else:
            store = simplekv.db.sql.SQLAlchemyStore(engine, metadata, 'sessions')

        # Attach session store
        flask_kvsession.KVSessionExtension(store, app)
```

Comment: I don't have everything set up to test it immediately. It sounds sensible, though. Thank you for a good explanation.